Mongoose Shows No Sign of Connection with Mac
mongoose.connect(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MONGO_URI)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
        app.listen(3001, () => {
            console.log("Server is Running on port 3001");
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB", err);
    });

Here is my standard way of connecting to mongoose. This code works on my pc but on my mac it simply goes to
"starting node index.js"
but doesn't show the "Connected to MongoDB" and the application still doesn't connect. The same code works on my pc so I was wondering if something on the mac is preventing me from connecting. Thank you

I've been trying to figure this out for like months. I got it fixed by doing brew install mongoose
